# Use or don't use 'this' within a object

Tags: c++, methods, this, member

My question refers to the case when I want to call other methods of the same class. Where's the difference of doing this with and without the use of 'this'? The same with variables of the class. Is there a difference accessing those variables through 'this'? Is it related to whether those methods / variables are private / public? Example:

```
class A {
private:
    int i;
    void print_i () { cout << i << endl; }

public:
    void do_something () {

        this->print_i();    //call with 'this', or ...
        print_i();          //... call without 'this'

        this->i = 5;        //same with setting the member;
        i = 5;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it's a question of style.  All of the places I've
worked have preferred not using the `this->`, except when
necessary.

There are cases where it makes a difference:

```
int func();

template <typename Base>
class Derived : public Base
{
    int f1() const
    {
        return func();      //  calls the global func, above.
    }
    int f2() const
    {
        return this->func();  //  calls a member function of Base
    }
};
```

In this case, `this->` makes the name of the function dependent,
which in turn defers binding to when the template is
instantiated.  Without the `this->`, the function name will be
bound when the template is defined, without considering what
might be in `Base` (since that isn't known when the template is
defined).

Answer (score 1):

There's no *functional* difference at all. But sometimes you need to explicitly include the `this` as a hint to the compiler; for example, if the function name is ambiguous on its own:

```
class C
{
   void f() {}

   void g()
   {
      int f = 3;
      this->f(); // "this" is needed here to disambiguate
   }
};
```

[James Kanze's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24454356/3549027) also explains a case where the explicit use of `this` changes which version of an overloaded name the compiler selects.

Comment: The most often case where it matters is in templates.  `this->` renders the function name dependent.

Comment: @James. Agreed; edited a bit.